# About Blogger Variables Definitions

Tags: css, variables, blogger, definitions

I develop blogger template and I was add Variables Definitions to make it fully customization, but I only know about three types colors / fonts / length
only change colors or fonts or control the width of container and left / right sidebars, but I want to add columns for example on the footer section as default is 3 columns, but if someone of my clients want 4 columns he can do that only from customize. So please can someone tell me what is the type of that?
and I see something is very awesome here in Layout :

```
https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en
```

that mean is possible to do that like this image :

[image]

How to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [macro variables](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/INxeiHd3DzM/0r7KwjZue2EJ).
Explore the "Simple" templates in order to better understanding the structure of these variables.